# Get controller not working with Ember.textfield

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
App.PhotoUpload = Ember.TextField.extend
  type: "file"

  change: (evt) ->
      # @get('controller') gives - App.PhotoUpload
      @get('controller').send('uploadImage')
```

In above code,if I debug it and check `@get('controller').constructor` it returns `App.PhotoUpload`, which is not right and it doesn't call uploadImage action which is in my route.

When I change Ember.TextField to Ember.View, `@get('controller')` works as expected and uploadImage action is called. But, as Im doing auto update to server on image upload, I need to stick with TextField.

I have these questions:
1. What are ways to access another controller from Emberview ?
2. How can I get access to right controller from Ember.TextField ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the included input fields were recently modified to [extend Ember.Component](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_field.js#L30) instead of Ember.View. One of the primary differences between a component and a view is that the controller property of a component [is itself](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/component.js#L102). Honestly, I'm not totally sure why that change was made. Having said that, it's still possible to access the controller from the context of where the text field was defined using the [targetObject property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_targetObject).

**Update:**

I looked into this a bit more and it turns out that not all input fields were turned into components, only the TextField and TextArea. It appears the primary reason for turning them into components was to expose [some helpful action handlers](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js#L104) since components provide that capability.